# Quillen's Finite Tor dimension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Quillen defines a morphism $f:X→Y$ to be "of finite tor dimension" if $\mathcal{O}_X$ is of finite tor dimension as a module over $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_Y)$. 
The question is if there are sufficient conditions for $f$ to be of finite tor dimension, which are not too difficult to check.

Comment: It suffices for $X$ to be regular.  Are you specifically interested in the non-regular case?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg: don't you mean Y? (another tautologically sufficient condition is for f to be flat)

Comment: Yes, I meant $Y$.

Comment: The other straightforward case is when $X$ is a closed subscheme of $Y$, with the ideal of $X$ locally generated by a regular sequence, but I expect you already know this too.

Comment: I am specifically interested in case Y is not regular. Is there a good condition in case Y is integral and f is proper surjective?